# MD5 CC_MD5 works different with iPad 64bit then simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, md5

I am using the below code to hash a string with md5. It worked fine until I tested my app on an iPad Air which is 64-bit. Then it generated a different output compared to the simulator.

For example the string `@"1111"`:

- On the simulator = B59C67BF196A4758191E42F76670CEBA
- On the iPad Air = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e

This is my code:

```
- (NSString *)MD5String
{    
    const char *cstr = [self UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[16];
    CC_MD5(cstr, strlen(cstr), result);

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:
            @"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
            result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3],
            result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
            result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11],
            result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15]
            ];
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: Btw. d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e *cannot* be the output of your method because your method creates only upper-case letters.

Answer (score 2):

d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e is the MD5 hash of an empty string. It looks like the bug is in the code that gets the string, not the MD5 algorithm.

Answer (score -2):

actually in iPad device sometimes it automatically make first letter capital so md5 encryption output varies.
so make sure that it is not happening in your case.